# NodeJS MongoDB Callback Hell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm still having trouble with conditionals and database callbacks, I wrote a routing function that querys for a violation object and this is from a form filled out in the client side. I am trying to change the user that owns this violation as an option, I query for that user and return it fine however at the if statement, x != y will always return true because of the nature of how I wrote this. I want it to finish querying, and then hit the conditional. I feel kind of stuck on how to go about this.

```
 if(viol.user != user[0]._id)
```

That way when I edit the user who owns that violation or object, the user doesn't add the same object to itself over and over again.

```
app.post('/singleViolation/:violation', isAdmin, function(req, res) {
     var violation = req.params.violation;


     Violation.findById(violation, function(err, viol){
         if (err) throw err;
         if (req.body.cause === '') {
                req.body.cause = viol.cause;
            }
            if (req.body.date === '') {
                req.body.date = viol.date;
            }
            if (req.body.location === '') {
                req.body.location = viol.location;
            }


            if(req.body.email === '') {
                req.body.email == viol.user;
            }

            if( req.body.email != '') {

                User.find({"local.email" : req.body.email}, function (err, user) {


                    if (err) {
                        req.body.email = viol.user;
                    }

                    if(viol.user != user[0]._id) {
                        typeof viol.user;
                        typeof user[0].id;
                        console.log(viol.user);
                        console.log(user[0]._id);
                        console.log(viol.user === user[0].id);
                        viol.user = user[0];
                        viol.save();

                        user[0].local.violations.push(viol);
                        Vehicles.findById(viol.vehicle, function(err, veh) {

                            user[0].local.vehicles.push(veh);
                            veh.owner = user[0];
                            veh.save();
                            user[0].save();

                        });

                    }
                });
            }

            viol.cause = req.body.cause;
            viol.date = req.body.date;
            viol.location = req.body.location;

            viol.save();

     });
     res.json(req.body);
 });
app.get('/editViolations/:violations', isAdmin, function(req, res) {
    res.render('editViolations.ejs');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Events in order to achieve what you want. Below is just a high-level solution.

- Trigger an Event when quering is finished.
- Associate the above event to you condition statement.
- Trigger another event when you meet your required condition.
- Associate this event with your return statement.

Read [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-nodes-event-module--net-35941) good tutplus blog to wrap your head around node [event module](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should first go through the concepts of callback functions and how to avoid callback hell
Below links would help you kick start with callbacks

1. [understanding callback functions](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)
2. [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)